# Adding to a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this issue where I am trying to add values from one array to another that's nested under the original array's name.

For example, this script returns an array:

```
<?php
return array (
'HTTP' => array(

    'GET' => array(

        '/' => function() {

        },

    ),

    'POST' => array(

        '/' => function($username, $password) {

        },

    )

),

'HTTPS' => array(

    'GET' => array(

        '/account/(:num)' => function($number) {

        }

    )
)
```

Then I have a class with a var of:

```
private $routes = array(
    'HTTP' => array(
        'GET'  => array(),
        'POST' => array()
    ),
    'HTTPS' => array(
        'GET'  => array(),
        'POST' => array()
    ),
    'FILTRERS' =>
        'BEFORE' => array(),
        'AFTER' => array()
);
```

What I am doing is using `glob` to read all the files, but the issue I can't work out is how to loop though all the arrays from the first scrsipt and push them into the var.

var would be:

```
 private $routes = array(
    'HTTP' => array(
        'GET'  => array(
             'example' => array(
                 '/' => function() {

                  },
             )
        ),
        'POST' => array(
             'example' => array(
                 '/account/(:num)' => function($number) {

                  },
             )
        )
    ),
    'HTTPS' => array(
        'GET'  => array(
             'example' => array(
                 '/' => function() {

                  },
             )
        ),
        'POST' => array()
    ),
    'FILTRERS' =>
        'BEFORE' => array(),
        'AFTER' => array()
);
```

The only why I can think of is using around four nested `foreach`es, or duplicating the code for each array set

Comment: Use a recursive function

Comment: I am not sure how I would go about using recursive function as I am not sure how to push into the nested array. because array_push adds to the end of the main array.

Comment: Where does `'example'` come from? And should `'FILTRERS'` be `'FILTERS'` (without the extra `R`)?

Comment: @David ahh I did not see that thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first array is stored in `$input` you can use this. I have hard-coded `'example'` based on your expected output.

```
foreach ($input as $protocol => $methods) {
    foreach ($methods as $method => $routeArray) {
        $routes[$protocol][$method]['example'] = $routeArray;
    }
}
```